# postgresql plpgsql: not able to iterate over a array of varchar[] type

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

i am trying to check if a element is present in an array using plpgsql.

and i am receiving "array subscript must have integer" error while executing the function.

select test('IND') should return true and select test('ING') should return false

Below is the code

```
create or replace function test(country varchar) 
returns varchar
language plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
   results varchar;
   countryarr varchar[3];
   i varchar[];
begin  
   countryarr := array['IND','USA','MEX'];

   foreach i slice 1 in array countryarr
    loop
      if countryarr[i]=country
         then results := 'TRUE';
      else
          results := 'FALSE';
      end if;
    end loop;

   return results;
 end;
 $function$
 ;
```

Comment: instead of a loop, a simple `return SELECT country = ANY(countryarr)` does not work? even better: you probably do not need a function to perform this test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `i` is defined as a `varchar[]` in your code.  It cannot be used as an `integer`.

You want something like this:

```
create or replace function test(country varchar) 
returns varchar
language plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
   countryarr varchar[3];
   i text;
begin  
   countryarr := array['IND','USA','MEX'];

   foreach i in array countryarr
    loop
      if i = country
         then return 'TRUE';
      end if;
    end loop;

   return 'FALSE';
 end;
 $function$
 ;
```

A better solution for what you are trying to achieve is:

```
create or replace function test(country varchar) 
returns varchar
language sql
AS $function$
  select case
           when country = any(array['IND', 'USA', 'MEX']) then 'TRUE' 
           else 'FALSE' 
         end;
$function$;
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, but when i tried to execute the updated code, i was always getting true for 'MEX' and false for 'IND' and 'USA' even though it is still present in the array...

Comment: @Nasir Sorry.  I did not see the logic error as I was focused on the `foreach. . . loop`.  I have updated my answer to address it.

Answer (score 0):

Let your function return a boolean. Then it reduces to a single SQL statement.

```
create or replace function is_valid_country(country_in varchar) 
  returns boolean
  language sql
  immutable strict 
AS $$
  select country_in = any(array['IND', 'USA', 'MEX']) ;
$$;

with test(country) as
   ( values ('IND'), ('USA'), ('MEX'), ('CAN'),('UK') ) 
select country, is_valid_country(country) is_valid 
  from test;
```

This can be used in any subsequent sql statement. And the optimizer can in-line it.